# Nested DQL User Defined Functions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, user-defined-functions, dql

It is working if I return the Custom function in one return but I would like to split it up into two different User Defined Functions.

Following the example here:

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

This is an example of my query with the nested functions

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE 
    FUNC_1(FUNC_2('field_name'),'constraint_default') = 
        FUNC_1(FUNC_2('value_entered'),'constraint_entered')
```

Example Function

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class BarFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringExpression = null;
    public $trimValueExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->trimValueExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'FUNC_1(' .
            $this->stringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' .
            $this->trimValueExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
            ')';
    }
}
```

now FUNC_2 is very close to FUNC_1 but never gets called as I think FUNC_1 returns the parsed syntax which removes the syntax needed for FUNC_2.

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class FooFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'FUNC_2(' .
            $this->stringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')';
    }
}
```

Now I've created a combined function that works:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class CombinedFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringExpression = null;
    public $trimValueExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->trimValueExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'FUNC_1(FUNC_2(' .
            $this->stringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . '),' .
            $this->trimValueExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
            ')';
    }
}
```

But I wanted to know if it's possible to use the two separate functions that are nested instead of creating this combined function?

Thoughts?

UPDATE:

Adding the yml config

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...

    orm:        
        entity_managers:
            foo_manager:
                dql:
                    numeric_functions:
                        FUNC_1: Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction\BarFunction
                        FUNC_2: Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction\FooFunction
                        COMB_FUNC: Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\DQL\NumericFunction\CombinedFunction
```

UPDATE #2

So FUNC_1 would match this

```
FUNC_1(value_of_func_2,'constraint_default')
```

And FUNC_2 would match this

```
FUNC_2('field_name')
```

Comment: Does parser not take care of that? AFAIK, ArithmeticPrimary can be a function expression. And do you call it as `DQL_F1(DQL_F2(...), ...)` in DQL?

Comment: @meze yes, when I was trying the individual functions I called it like FUNC_1(FUNC_2 as that's how I aliased it in the yml config, added config

Comment: Hm it worked for me: `AND FUNC_1(FUNC_2('field_name','TEST'),'constraint_default') = FUNC_1(FUNC_2('field_name','TEST'),'constraint_default')` was generated. Could you share FooFunction?

Comment: FooFunction would only match FUNC_2 'FUNC_2('field_name','TEST')' it's pretty much the same but I don't need to check '),' because this is checked by FUNC_1

Comment: Actually you need to check for `)`. FUNC_1 can only see FUNC_1(expr1, expr2), in other words it sees only a comma.

Comment: So in the BarFunction don't check for the comma? Could you explain a little more? Submit detailed answer?

Answer (score 1):

I defined FUNC_2 as:

```
class FooFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'FUNC_2(' .
            $this->stringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

And it generated the right sql for me: FUNC_1(FUNC_2(123),123) = FUNC_1(FUNC_2(123),123)

Comment: LOL that is my exact function but when it parses for me I get FUNC_1(123) = FUNC_1(123). Is FUNC_1 wrong?

Comment: I've added FUNC_2 to my question

Comment: May be a bug in 2.0.x? I'm using 2.3.3-DEV with your classes' code

Comment: hmm using 2.3.0, maybe this is a bug. Thanks for you efforts +1

Comment: @PhillPafford works on 2.3.0 too ;s If it had a bug, it would produce FUNC_1(,123) at least.